# how can select from table use in operator with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have 2 table - users and posts.
I get users list with next sql request :

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE some_param = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

$result - Array.

After how I can get element from posts with $result?

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts where user_id in ($result)";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

But don't work it, please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sub-queries to avoid running queries for multiple times.

Through this you can get expected data in one go.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts where user_id in (
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE some_param = 1
)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single query for this purpose by joining the tables

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts inner join users on users.user_id = posts.user_id  
        WHERE users.some_param = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**implode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts 
         WHERE user_id IN (". implode(',',$result) .")";
```

Even you directly write the sub query like

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts 
         WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE some_param = 1)";
```

Also so many result in [**this**](https://www.google.co.in/#q=select+rows+from+array++mysql)